# Eclipse: refocus the main editor window after Open Resource (and other dialogs)

Tags: eclipse

When I'm working with Eclipse, I fill my main monitor with an editor and break out all the panels (Navigator, Console, Problems, etc) onto my secondary monitor.

I've noticed, though when I open a dialog (for example, Open Resource) then cancel it (eg, by hitting escape), the focus is shifted from the main editor window to one of the broken-out panels.

Is there any way to prevent this? Or, failing that, is there some shortcut for "refocus the main editor"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably not an ideal solution, but you can use the universal <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>3</kbd> to navigate to the editor (you will have to select it by typing e.g. *editor* the first time, after that it will be selected by default, so you can then just hit enter). I had a look at the Window -> Navigation menu and there's actually a shortcut for what you want: Activate Editor (<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F12</kbd>)

Comment: Awesome - the Activate Editor shortcut did the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In my eclipse the shortcut was set to just "F12", don't know why.

I rebound it to ALT+SHIFT+Q,E.

This is done via the Preferences:

General >> Keys

Set 'Activate Editor' to any shortcut you like.
Also I have set 'When' to 'In Windows' and 'Category' to 'Window'.