# How to make Eclipse Open Resource in the Current Editor Window?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-indigo

I like having multiple editor windows in eclipse, and use Open Resource (Ctrl-Shift-R) a lot.

Unfortunately, I always expect (and **want**) the resource to be opened in the current editor window (the one with focus). However, if I currently have that resource open (as a tab) in another editor, that tab will fill that editor, rather than opening in the current editor.

This is incredibly frustrating behaviour as the file in the editor being replaced is often the very file that I want to reference while opening the new one. How do I stop it, and make Eclipse behave sanely?

Comment: Any luck on resolving this issue?

Comment: Well, what I've done is limit the number of open editors to 2, have them side by side, and then it always opens in the other editor. This makes the behaviour of opening it in the other editor, and having it already open in that editor equivalent.
You can do this in Preferences->General->Editors, tick 'close editors automatically' and set the 'Number of opened editors before closing: 2', and things should be almost alright.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Eclipse: refocus the main editor window after Open Resource (and other dialogs)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2058873/eclipse-refocus-the-main-editor-window-after-open-resource-and-other-dialogs)