# In Eclipse, how to maintain editor focus after opening a resource?

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu

**Similarly related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9763252/how-to-make-eclipse-open-resource-in-the-current-editor-window) question.**

As a Java developer, I'm frequently switching between classes. Using the open resource shortcut (Ctrl + Shift + R) has been an absolute time saver, and I use it very often. Recently, I switched from Windows XP/Eclipse Indigo to Ubuntu 12.04/Eclipse Juno. My setup consists of dual monitors with the Eclipse editor open on one and a few panels on the other (namely the console and package explorer). I've noticed, however, that when I open a resource using this setup, after the resource opens, the focus moves to one of the panels that I have 'broken' out and moved off to the side. It does this even though focus was previously in the editor window. Since I had been using Indigo previously on Windows, without issue, I thought perhaps it was an Juno issue, so I tried the same thing using Indigo on Ubuntu (using a plain, vanilla setup), but the issue persists. This leads me to believe that it's an Eclipse + Ubuntu (or GTK) issue. In Ubuntu, what determines who gets the focus when a dialog is dismissed?

I'm aware that there are shortcuts for refocusing to the editor, but unfortunately, this is a major distraction. Has anybody else faced a similar situation, and if so, how did you overcome it?

Comment: Did you find a solution in the end? This really looks like a bug to me.